# HTML/CSS Layout Inquiry

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to get my HTML/CSS to follow this particular format:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTBmn.jpg

I've already attempted to search for the code online, but it would not work for me whenever I tested it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your basic HTML inside the body tags:

```
<div id="navbar">
</div>
<div id="textbox">
</div>
<div id="lmodule">
</div>
<div id="rmodule">
</div>
```

This is your CSS in your dedicated CSS file.

```
#navbar {
width: 100%;
height: auto; (or if you have specific height put it)
(position: fixed; - use this if you want your menu to stay with the viewer upon moving up/down the page)
}
#textbox {
width: 60%; (based on your image I believe it is around 60%)
height: auto;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#lmodule {
display: inline-box;
width: 27%;
height: auto;
float: left;
margin: 0 3% 0 auto;
}
#rmodule {
display: inline-box;
width: 27%;
height: auto;
float: right;
margin: 0 auto 0 3%;
}
```

This is at least how I do it. I use % based values, because it is easy to make media queries this way.

Comment: This is perfect! Was able to mold it from there. Thank you! =]

Comment: No problem, as long as it helped you ^_^